# Checkov attribute reference

Tags: terraform, policy, checkov

I am currently learning policy-as-code with the help of Checkov. In the process, I am also writing my own policies.

I would like to write a policy that checks the content inside "managed_rule_set".
I know how to reference the attributes from the terraform-file correctly, but not how to do it in this particular case. I define the custom policies via a yaml-file and orient myself on the documentation of checkov.

Terraform-file:
[tf-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGTnB.png)

```
    resource "azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy" "waf_network" {
  name                = "waf-${var.tag_project}-network-${var.tag_environment}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_network.name
  location            = "azurerm_resource_group.rg_network.location"
  
  policy_settings {
    enabled = true
    mode    = "Prevention"
  }

  managed_rules {
    managed_rule_set {
      type    = "OWASP"
      version = "3.1"
    }
    managed_rule_set {
      type    = "Microsoft_BotManagerRuleSet"
      version = "0.1"
    }
  }

  tags = merge(local.common_tags, local.intrinsic_tags)
}
```

Has anyone an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code in the question and not using a screenshot. It's much easier for someone to try and reproduce problems that way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

depending on what you want to achieve you can use `.*.` to reference all the `managed_rule_set` blocks, like that

```
- cond_type: "attribute"
resource_types: 
    - "azurerm_web_application_firewall_policy"
    attribute: "managed_rules.managed_rule_set.*.type"
    operator: "contains"
    value: "OWASP"
```

Comment: Yes thank you. That's exactly what I've been looking for.

Comment: Ok so this worked. I can validate the value of "type" for managed_rule_set.
Is their a way to proof the value of "version" in managed_rule_set? 

I have tried it with this attribute (not working): "managed_rules.managed_rule_set.*.version"

Comment: Have you seen the `Evaluating list attributes` section here: https://www.checkov.io/3.Custom%20Policies/YAML%20Custom%20Policies.html